# Algorithm to find $k$ points with maximal minimum distance

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry

In a post, the question of how to find *k* points with minimal diameter among *N* points in the plane is raised. Here, I consider the dual problem.

Given points [image], we wish to find a subset *I* of size *k*, solving the following problem

[image]

Is there an algorithm for that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, not one in P. Seems like there's a reduction from 3SAT.

Comment: I think this is solvable in O(nlogn) in 1D, but not sure about 2D

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you could try looking at how points are found in photon mapping (a rendering technique). A map of points is created. The task is then to find points within some distance from a starting point. I believe this can be done in O(log n). If you loop over you points, and use the nearest neighbour method, you should have a O(n log n). TLDR: Try looking at photon mapping and kd-trees.

Comment: I'd still love to see an answer to this question. I've looked around and only gotten half-answers-- which might be more helpful if I had a background in graph theory, but unfortunately, I don't and a lot of the suggestions just go over my head.